# Finding regular expression in a range in python dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am facing a problem

I have a dataframe named employer which looks like:

```
employer
------------
wings brand activation i pvt ltd
hofincons infotech &industrial services pvt .ltd
bharat fritz werner bangalore
kludi rak indpvt ltd.
```

Another dataframe which maps the employer name to the category which looks like(call it pincode):

```
Index   Name                                    FINAL_CATEGORY
68781   central board of excise and customs     cat b
68782   c a g hotels pvt ltd                    cat b
68783   avaneetha textiles pvt ltd              cat a
68784   trendy wheels pvt ltd                   cat a+
68785   wings brand activations india pvt ltd   cat b
```

Now I want to emulate something like:

```
pincode[pincode['Compnay Name'].str.contains('wings brand activation i pvt ltd')]

Compnay Name    FINAL_CATEGORY
____________________________________

pincode[pincode['Compnay Name'].str.contains('wings brand activation i pvt')]

Compnay Name    FINAL_CATEGORY
____________________________________

pincode[pincode['Compnay Name'].str.contains('wings brand activation i')]


Compnay Name    FINAL_CATEGORY
____________________________________

pincode[pincode['Compnay Name'].str.contains('wings brand activation')]

        Name                                    FINAL_CATEGORY
68785   wings brand activations india pvt ltd   cat b
```

As you can see, for each string I am reducing the length till last space starting from end of the string and then searching.

The above need to be put in loop with (i think regex). So that for every entry in employer table, it searches for entire range of pincode and figure out the closest match. If nothing then return nan.

Thanks in advance, as the problem is a bit tricky to put in words, please ask for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iterative approach as follows:

```py
def find_substr(employer, pincode):
    employer = employer.set_index("employer")
    for words in employer.index.map(str.split):
        length = len(words)
        found = False
        while length > 0 and not found:
            substr = ' '.join(words[:length]).replace('(', '\(')
            mask = pincode.Name.str.contains(substr)
            if mask.any():
                employer.loc[' '.join(words), 'cat'] = pincode.loc[mask, 'FINAL_CATEGORY'].values[0]
                found = True
            length -= 1
    employer = employer.reset_index()
    return employer

employer = find_substr(employer, pincode)
print(employer)
```

```
                                           employer    cat
0                  wings brand activation i pvt ltd  cat b
1  hofincons infotech &industrial services pvt .ltd    NaN
2                     bharat fritz werner bangalore    NaN
3                              kludi rak indpvt ltd    NaN
```

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-d9ad96b38e32> in <module>
----> 1 employers = find_substr(data, pincode)

<ipython-input-77-4de374ae763d> in find_substr(employer, pincode)
      8             mask = pincode.Name.str.contains(substr)
      9             if mask.any():
---> 10                 employer.loc[' '.join(words), 'cat'] = pincode.loc[mask, 'FINAL_CATEGORY'].values
     11                 found = True

Comment: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (30,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (1373,)

Comment: You must have multiple lines corresponding matching the substring. If you are positive there is only one category, you can take `....values[0]`

Comment: yes sir, there can be more than one value, pincode is unique while employer can have multiple values (more than one employee has same employer), basically key value pairing needs to be done.

Comment: Ok but one employer is mapped to only one category ? If so, just add an indexer  like so: `pincode.loc[mask, 'FINAL_CATEGORY'].values[0]`

Comment: It worked like a charm, till i got an employer like ['tyco', 'electronics', 'corporation', '(', 'i', ')', 'pvt', 'ltd'], 
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 29

I tried real hard, but unable to do so.. can u please?

Comment: This is because `(` is a special regex character. I edited the answer to take this case into account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it.

First transform your pins df into a dictionary that maps the strings to the corresponding category. Then use a double list comprehension to create a cat column of your employee dataframe to record all the categories that match his name:

```
# Example df
employer = pd.DataFrame({"employer":["wings brand activation i pvt ltd", "bharat fritz werner bangalore"]})
pins = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["trendy wheels pvt ltd", "wings brand activation i pvt ltd"], "FINAL_CATEGORY":["cat a+", "cat b"]}) 

dict_pins = dict(zip(pins['Name'], pins['FINAL_CATEGORY']))
employer['cat'] = [[dict_pins[key] for key in dict_pins.keys() if x in key] for x in employer['employer']]
```

---

Output:

```
                           employer      cat
0  wings brand activation i pvt ltd  [cat b]
1     bharat fritz werner bangalore       []
```